# Showing menu depending on authenticated User : Using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I already did a research, I found one way using `<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">`. but unfortunately sec taglib is not working for me. I tried every single solution in the web but in vain.

Is there any other way to show content depending on user without using taglib ?

Comment: You can pass your user object to your page and do some if statements depending on user role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, obviously there was a conflict, I had to exclude manually each spring-security-taglib dependency.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added the spring-security-taglibs library to your project.

For example, if you are using maven for resolving the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: When I add it, I've got this exception : **No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath** . when I remove it the application runs perfectly !